# Unsandwiching multiple erc20 transfers

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design

How can I un-sandwich multiple transfers from a batch transfer? Basically, I want to execute i.e. 30 transfers and have them show up as individual transfers on Etherscan rather than a sandwich tx that contains all the 30 transfers? is it possible to create a function that does such on-chain or is it only possible by using web3 and building a script that fires off single transfers?

Answer (score 1):

It is the way etherscan display "internal transactions", the token transfers are under the same transaction hash and they are displayed together.

If the requirement is to display them as individual operations then each has to have their own transaction hash. It is not possible with a contract since transfers will be "internal transactions" with the same hash. Using an script is the only option.